# Identifying outliers in time series with decompose in R

Tags: r, time-series, seasonality, decomposition

I have time series data, from a period in which it is reasonable to assume the seasonality is the. I used `decompose` in R to get a multiplicative decomposition. I know, ex-ante, periods where I think there is new information or a change in data behaviour. This last assertion is confirmed with large random components of the decomposition in those periods.

I did not use STL because the seasonal component is not a problem, it should not change. So I think the advantages of STL over the classical decomposition are almost worthless in this case.

This seems to be simple and works in the sense that the series seems to be regular except for large random component in the period with an outlier. Do you think there is a better way to address this?

Comment: You used `decomposite` in R? I suppose it was `decompose`.

Comment: @RichardHardy Sorry, edited.